# Add quotes to each word of string in column of pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I have a Pandas dataframe something like below:

| CANDIDATE_ID | Job1_Skill1 |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | "Oracle" AND "Python" |
| 13 | asset management, business Management, Oracle DBA |
| 14 | UX, UI, UE4, Photoshop |
| 15 | "Business Developer" |

I want to add double quotes to each word which does not already have it also replace "," with word "AND" . My final dataFrame should look like below:

| CANDIDATE_ID | Job1_Skill1 |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | "Oracle" AND "Python" |
| 13 | "asset management" AND "business Management" AND "Oracle DBA" |
| 14 | "UX" AND "UI" AND "UE4" AND "Photoshop" |
| 15 | "Business Developer" |

I am using python 3.8 for it. Can anyone suggest a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

So, given the following dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "CANDIDATE_ID": {0: 12, 1: 13, 2: 14, 3: 15},
        "Job1_Skill1": {
            0: 'Oracle AND "Python"',
            1: "asset management, business Management, Oracle DBA",
            2: "UX, UI, UE4, Photoshop",
            3: "Business Developer",
        },
    }
)
```

You can do it using Pandas method chaining, like this:

```py
df["Job1_Skill1"] = (
    df["Job1_Skill1"]
    .str.replace('"', "")
    .str.replace(",", " AND")
    .apply(lambda x: " AND ".join(f"'{word}'" for word in x.split(" AND ")))
)
```

Which outputs the desired result:

```py
   CANDIDATE_ID                                                    Job1_Skill1
0            12                                          'Oracle' AND 'Python'
1            13  'asset management' AND 'business Management' AND 'Oracle DBA'
2            14                        'UX' AND 'UI' AND 'UE4' AND 'Photoshop'
3            15                                           'Business Developer'
```